# What is the strongest crop in Banished?

Tags: banished

I have observed that some crops seem to withstand colder weathers than others. For example, squash dies at around 25f while cabbage dies at 32f. Which crop can withstand the coldest weather?

Answer (score 5):

Despite what appears to be common belief here, squash are the most resilient to cold, being able to go down to 25f. From the resource files:

- Squash:

  - float _growthTemp = 55.0;
  - float _growthTempRange = 30.0;
- Pumpkin:

  - float _growthTemp = 60.0;
  - float _growthTempRange = 20.0;

However, it also appears that snow kills all crops, regardless of temperature tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

In Banished, Pumpkins are the crops that are able to stand up to the most frost and cold. If you use them, make sure to plant them so they are ready for Winter as well as the first few weeks of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Pumpkins are the most resilient plant in the game. Though I have some uncertainties in my answer, just from reading the comments on the Wiki, and several other resources, I do believe that pumpkins are the most resilient plant.

Answer (score 0):

Pumpkins i believe, as i read on the Wiki.