# Crop growing speeds

Tags: banished

Looking at [this calculator](http://banishedinfo.com/t/Size_calculator/crops), it doesn't differentiate between the different crop types.  I read somewhere that the different crops grow at different speeds, but I can't find any definitive information on the relative crop growing speeds.

All I've found are that beans are the fastest-growing of the crops, followed by wheat.

Does anyone know how fast the individual crops grow, relative to each other?

Comment: The only thing I've seen on this topic is on [Reddit.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Banished/comments/1z9cms/did_some_science_regarding_farms/) I suspect that there is more to the story than just this measure of speed, for example, [crops are affected differently by the cold.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159097/13396)

Comment: @tugs : That question (essentially) has no answer, do you have any info on a link between crops and temperature?

Comment: @bd33 again, the best link I can find is [on reddit.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Banished/comments/1yve3l/a_look_at_crops_and_orchards_tips_and_tricks/cfoo71x)

Comment: Anecdotally, I have noticed that when I assign farmers to my cabbage and corn fields of roughly the same size, the cabbage takes longer to get started and is harvested later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, crops grow at different speeds and have different tolerances to cold temperatures.  This is unrelated to the purpose of the calculator to which you link.

The calculator highlights how many food units can be produced (total and per laborer) in an *ideal* growing year for *any* given crop with a particular sized field.  Also given that pestilence can ruin fields in an area for a particular crop, it is important that fields be crop agnostic.  So it helps you create fields that are a good geometry for the available land.

That said, most years are not ideal.  If you're doing things right, you should either be bumping up against your food quota during harvest time or preemptively squirreling food away in your trading post(s).  In a fair year, your bean crops may be completely harvested to ideal quantities and when the pumpkin harvest comes along some are left to die on the vine due to your quotas.  In a year where temperatures dive early, you could easily loose half your bean harvest, and be saved by your squash and pumpkins.  The vagaries  of weather are outside the scope of that calculator.  Growing a variety of crops is a good way to cope with what the game throws your way.